# Heroku Repo Size and Slug Size increase with each deployment. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I change some text in my application and deploy new version with

`git push heroku master`

But everytime I push, it increase a lot. I write here the increasement after each deploy.

```
168.2 KB
37.9 MB

178.6 KB
38.7 MB

187 KB
39.4 MB

194 KB
40.2 MB

205.3 KB
40.9 MB

232.8 KB
41.8 MB

277.9 KB
42.4 MB

286.5 KB
43 MB
```

If i select all my folders in my app project (including public/, tmp/ and log/ that I ignore with slugignore e gitignore) total size is only 198 KB.

**Why all this?**

Comment: If might be useful to show the output from your `git push` to Heroku.

Comment: What you mean specifically?

Comment: The size on heroku includes your app and all of its dependencies (ruby, rails, all your gems, etc.). On your development machine, the dependencies are not stored in the app directory.

Comment: Yes I know. But why it increase when i change only texts somewhere???

Comment: Something new? Any news?

Answer (score 9):

There are a few steps that can be followed to reduce the slug size.

**Purge build-cache**

Buildpacks cache some content to speed up future builds. But sometimes, when your dependencies change (especially when you remove a dependency), it might not be removed from the cache. So if you are facing unexpectedly high slug sizes and you have removed some dependencies from your project, try this first (if you can live with a slow build on the next deploy).

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-repo 
$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname
```

**Ignore files with .slugignore**

Your .sligignore should list directories and files that are in the repo (not ignored by .gitignore) but not needed for the app to run on prod. Some examples of files like these are the tests, documentation and design files. To remove these from the slug, create a .slugignore at the root of the project.

```
*.psd
/doc
/test
```

To check out what files are being put into the slug, you can also enter the heroku
bash and check the filesystem.

```
heroku run bash -a appname  
du -sh .[^.]* * | sort -hr
```

**Node modules**

This part is specific to apps that include an asset pipeline that bundles all JavaScript code to single script. If you are using a node server, this might not apply to you.

If you are using Rails with webpacker, you might have a lot of dependencies in node_modules. But after the asset pipeline compiles the resources, you probably don't need the node_modules directory (unless you run custom node scripts at runtime that use those modules). To remove the node_modules directory in this case, we can use the heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean buildpack with a .slug-post-clean file. The format of this file is the same as .gitignore or .sligignore, so just list out directories that you want to ignore from the final slug and they will be removed. One thing to make sure with the buildpack is that this should be the last one in the order otherwise it will remove the files before your actual buildpack runs.

But what if you are using custom node scripts that access the node_modules at runtime? In that case, what we do is move those scripts to a separate directory with it's own package.json file. To install the dependencies into that directory along with the installation of root package.json, add a postinstall script to your root package.json. This will instruct yarn to change directory to your custom script and install dependencies there after the dependencies of your root project are installed.

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "yarn --cwd lib/custom-node-script"
}
```

With this, you can then safely remove your root node_modules directory even when using custom node scripts in a production Rails app.

[Here is the detailed post](https://sapandiwakar.in/reducing-heroku-slug-size/) addressing the same issue.

Comment: I tried the purge cache commands before deplying and yes it did reduce the size back to normal. But i wanted to ask do we have to run both the commands again and again before deploying to heroku?

Comment: No, I have noticed that the cache needs to be purged only when you remove some dependencies. This is because heroku probably continues to keep those dependencies in the cache even though they are no longer required.

Comment: Okay so I followed this link : https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration . This uses a buildpack that caches node_modules everytime I push my code to heroku due to which the slug size increases. To bring the app back to its original slugsize I have to run the purge command. If you've tried de0loying your react app to heroku with this , can you tell me if there's a solution to make sure the slig size remains the same Everytime I push?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I don't understand why the slug size would keep on increasing. Even if it is caching node modules, unless you keep on adding/upgrading dependencies, it should remain constant. Is your build script generating some files with different names each time? If yes, you could you try to `slugingore` the file pattern and see if that helps.

Comment: How do i know if it's generating some files with different names each time?

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely due to build cache. To speed up build process, Heroku downloads dependencies, and over time it gets built up.

Use their repo plugin to purge build cache, and re-deploy. You will see the slug size being lowered.

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo

Here is more about their build cache: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#build-cache