# 'slug size too large' heroku, even after deleted mutiple files?

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku

I keep getting this slug size to big error I have 583 / 500. Ive tried deleted img files and using a .slugignore none of it changed anything.Ive heard you can reduce your requirements, but i need all these so i don't know how :/, ive already tryed clearing the cache of the build. Hope someone can help.

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.0.0
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
WTForms==2.3.3
SQLAlchemy==1.4.15
Pillow==8.2.0
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Login==0.5.0
itsdangerous==2.0.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
email-validator==1.1.2
python-dotenv==0.17.1
psycopg2==2.8.6
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
Pyrebase4==4.5.0
Keras==2.4.3
nltk==3.6.2
numpy==1.19.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and reduce your slug size in a number of ways. [Docs](https://help.heroku.com/KUFMEES1/my-slug-size-is-too-large-how-can-i-make-it-smaller)
The easiest is to add a `.slugignore` file to your application to tell the slug compiler to ignore any unnecessary files in your application, such as static assets.

To determine what files/folders are taking up space in your slug you can inspect you slug by starting up a one-off dyno like so:

heroku run bash -a

Once in the dyno you can use the du -ha --max-depth 1 /app | sort -hr command to show the files and folders in the current directory, ordered by size:

```sh
~ $ du -ha --max-depth 1 /app | sort -hr
108M    /app
99M     /app/vendor
8.1M    /app/.heroku
448K    /app/lib
292K    /app/spec
8.0K    /app/Gemfile.lock
4.0K    /app/Procfile
4.0K    /app/Gemfile
```

This can be helpful in determining where large files are.

You may also find that [clearing the build cache](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#build-cache) helps reduce the size of the slug.

Other Helpful resources : [Heroku Repo Size and Slug Size increase with each deployment. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167040/heroku-repo-size-and-slug-size-increase-with-each-deployment-why)

Answer (score 0):

the size is too large because of tensorflow module which is around 500 mb,
you can use tensorflow-cpu which may bring down your slug size to around 300 mb.

remove tensorflow dependency and add

```
tensorflow-cpu==2.5.0
```